# Filtering the data with certain keywords from the query digit postgresql

Tags: jquery, postgresql, filtering

I will look for the data digit to four-value of 007, when I use Like '%007% 'a lot of data that has a value of 007 instead of digits to four. How do I find the data that has value only 007 on the digit to four to six? thank you.

[image]

Comment: what is "digit to four"?

Comment: from fourth digit until sixth digit. sorry my english is bad :)

Comment: So, something, like `substring('002007914050529' from 4 for 3) = '007'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use like operator and know the exact position, use three uderscores in the beginning instead:

```
t=# select '12300789' like '___007%';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)

t=# select '12340789' like '___007%';
 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```